# Flask Request within request fails on production WSGI environment

Tags: apache, python-3.x, flask, python-requests, wsgi

I am making a request within a request, in order to accommodate my service oriented design. Locally, this code works. However on production using ubuntu libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3, my nested request fails.

A key point is both services exist within the same `<Virtualhost>` on the server, so I suspect this is a threading issue.

The second request called within `newitem()` fails with `ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused')` on my WSGI Ubuntu box even though the API endpoint functions as expected when I POST to it outside of this context (for example curl POST to the exact url).

Another important point is this request within reqest design works on my local when I have two separate flask apps running on different ports. I had this exact issue on my local until I ran the API server with `--threaded` flag.

My server is configured as follows:

**app2.wsgi:**

```
#!env/bin/python3
import sys, os
sys.path.append('/var/www/api_app')

from app import create_app
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

application = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

**apache2/sites-available/default.conf**:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # ------ WSGI config ------
        WSGIDaemonProcess app1 user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
        WSGIDaemonProcess app2 user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias /front_end /var/www/front_end/app2.wsgi
        WSGIScriptAlias /api_app /var/www/api_app/app2.wsgi
        WSGIScriptReloading On

            <Directory /var/www/api_app>
                    WSGIProcessGroup app2
                    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                    Order deny,allow
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            <Directory /var/www/front_end>
                    WSGIProcessGroup app1
                    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                    Order deny,allow
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**The following code works great on my local environment when I start the API service with the --threaded flag** It fails on WSGI Apache2 on the requests.post() line.

```
@plant_material.route('/plant_material/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def newitem():
    form = PlantMaterialForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        api_uri = current_app.config['API_SERVER_URI']
        url = api_uri + "api/plant_material/new"
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        print(request.form)
        r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(request.form), headers=headers)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return redirect(url_for('plant_material.index'))
        elif r.status_code == 401:
            flash('Whiteboard API Unauthorized')
        elif r.status_code == 403:
            flash('Whiteboard API Forbidden')
        elif r.status_code == 500:
            flash('Internal Server Error')
    return render_template('plant_material/new.html', form=form)
```

**How can I make a request within a request on my production server?**

Comment: Have you checked if the server firewall allows connections to `API_SERVER_URI` from your server? In other words, can you connect to the server from the same machine at all?

Comment: I ssh'd into the server then I CURL from the server it works: curl -v -L -G -d "q=&o=0&l=10&m=variety"  http://10.11.12.103/front_end/api/inventory ... produces JSON response

Comment: That's at least something. And you are 110% certain that the `request.post()` goes to that exact same URL, right? Just checking.

Comment: Yes. I can reproduce this bug, with a hardcoded URL, and it fails in the same way.

Comment: Hrmz, because there is no earthly reason that I can see that such a request from a WSGI daemon in one app group would get such *connection refused* errors when trying to connect to the public port for another group.

Comment: Which is why I made you test for firewall issues; presumbaly the `curl` command you used fails in the same manner when used in a `subprocess` invocation? Just to eliminate that this isn't something caused by `requests` (highly unlikely, but worth a try).

Comment: It looks like you are getting 100 bounty because I could not think on Friday. The URL was the issue this line fails "api_uri = current_app.config['API_SERVER_URI']" and returned nothing and my hardcoded URL was never tested on the server.

Comment: I've summarised my comments into an answer that should be helpful to future visitors too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache and mod_wsgi take care of concurrency here; there is no reason for a well-formed request from one WSGI app to another on the same server to fail here.

- Make sure that there is no firewall blocking requests to the server from localhost. Test the same URL from the command line with `curl` for example.
- Triple-check your assumptions; use the live value of `current_app.config['API_SERVER_URI']` when testing if your connections work, not what you assume it to be.
- swap out HTTP methods; try running `curl` from a `subprocess` call, or use `urllib2` to access the API